# accessing annotated queryset while writing Django test cases

Tags: django, django-testing

I'm trying to write a test case which makes use of an attribute that was added through annotation, but my test case could not use it, any ideas how can I fix it? thanks

the property in my model:

```
@property
def amount_net(self):
    net_sum = self.amount_net_sum
    return Decimal(round(net_sum, 2)) if net_sum else Decimal("0.00")
```

`self.amount_net_sum` comes from custom manager:

```
class InvoiceManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        qs = qs.annotate(amount_net_sum=Sum('line_items__amount_net'))
        return qs
```

in test case:

```
self.invoice_test1 = Invoice.objects.create(
            state=InvoiceStatus.NEW, language='en',
            type=InvoiceType.INVOICE,
            created=date(2015, 1, 30),
            recipient=profile, 
        )
```

and

```
self.assertEqual(self.invoice_test1.amount_net, self.line_item_sum_net,
                         'Checks if the invoice calculated and expected values are same')
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'Invoice' object has no attribute 'amount_net_sum'
```

Comment: You need to show more of your code; in particular, where `self.invoice_test1` is defined, and how you're calling that `get_queryset` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object `self.invoice_test1` was *created* using your code, it wasn't fetched from the database. Therefore your custom manager was not used and the object was not annotated.

If you refetch the object from the database, then it should be annotated. You can then use the refetched object in the `assertEqual` check.

```
self.invoice_test1 = Invoice.objects.get(pk=self.invoice_test1.pk)
```

You should probably alter the `amount_net` property to handle the case when the object has no `amount_net_sum` attribute, instead of letting it raise `AttributeError`.